# Fire Store two million reads and 4 gigabytes downloaded with 10 kb database and one user?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, I am testing out my app by myself. There are three main firestore accesses. First, every minute a cloud function runs on cloud firestore that queries for posts with expired timestamps, then deletes them if there are any. Second, there is a firestore cloud function that appends information to a post if the post gets enough likes. Third is the way the user accesses the database, through a query which retrieves all posts where the watchedBy child contains the user's ID.

From the function running every minute, I can expect 1440 reads a day. From the query to find a user's post, I can expect maybe 100-500 reads per day. However, when I logged into the google app engine, I inexplicably found 4 gigabytes of data downloaded and two million reads. Also, there were apparently 100,000 firestore API calls. This is while I am on the free tier of firebase, so I have no idea how the data even downloaded or where it's coming from - it's inexplicable and way more than expected. This randomly just happened today, as I have never seen this many reads. What seems to be the problem? Is someone else accessing the database? Is there some repeated loop keeps reading from the database?  I really have no idea where exactly two million reads could come from. I attached the function that runs every minute.

```js
exports.hourly_job = functions.pubsub.topic('hourly-tick').onPublish((change,context) => {
    const currentTime = Date.now()
    const getPostsForDate = admin.firestore().collection('posts').where('timeOfDeletion', '<', currentTime)
    return getPostsForDate.get().then(snapshot => {
        const updates = {}
        const batch = admin.firestore().batch()
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            var key = doc.id
            console.log(key)
            const convos =  admin.database().ref('/convoID/' + key).once('value', (snapshot) => {
                 if (snapshot.exists){
                     const convos = snapshot.val()
                     snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                        updates["conversations/" + child.key] = null
                    })
                 }
             })
             updates["/convoID/"+ key] = null
             updates["/reveals/" + key] = null
             updates["/postDetails/" + key] = null
             const postFireStoreRef = admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(key)
             const posterRef = admin.firestore().collection('posters').doc(key)
             batch.delete(postFireStoreRef)
             batch.delete(posterRef)
        })
        return admin.database().ref().update(updates), batch.commit()
})
})
```

[image: reads console]
[image: console[![][1]][1]]

[image: more console]

Comment: It seems unlikely that anyone here on Stack Overflow can help you with this. [Reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  I entered a support ticket linking them to this question. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems unlikely anyone here can help analyze this traffic without access to the project.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the firebase team is looking at it and this is the main resource they have related to the question, can they take a look at it first?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I can email them, if that seems better. I'll do that,

Comment: Hi @RaimKhalil, How this situation has evolved. It's a little bit scary that we can't find any interpretations of situations like yours. Do you know what was the reason of millions of API calls? What is the limit?